# Noob help with Jquery input Form, Focus, Blur, Keypress - Cursor Not Changing?

Tags: jquery, input, cursor, hover, tumblr

I am having trouble building a Form with some fancy jquery, similar to tumblr's website.

- I am using the pluggin from this link
  http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/infield/

This is what I have working with so far
http://www.messtudios.com/form/index2.html

What I want to do but can't figure out is changing the cursor:pointer to cursor:text, after you have click on an input field.

Similar to Tumblr login or signup form.

Right now the Label is positioned over the field and will only accept:hover, and not :focus because its the Label.

Any help will be much appreciate in advance, thanks.

If I removed the label width and padding, it works only in the area the label text isn't ( still not acceptable although looks more like in the direction I want to go, however when u hover over the label text the cursor turns into a pointer again )

Adding this worked.
var $input = $('input');
$input.focus(function(){$(this).prev().css('cursor','text')});
$input.blur(function(){$(this).prev().css('cursor','pointer')});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You should be able to do this entirely with css. For the example given just add -</strike>

```
label.infield{
    cursor: text;
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to get all fancy with it, the following seems to do the trick :)

```
var $input = $('input');
$input.focus(function(){$(this).prev().css('cursor','text')});
$input.blur(function(){$(this).prev().css('cursor','pointer')});
```

Comment: I updated the link with ur css code.. However now there is no pointer, and I want it to start with a pointer then go to Text when you click:focus

Comment: Thanks, it worked I had to remove the css though that u added above